# Module installed from npm can't find it's local files

Tags: node.js, npm

I published a small package to npm which consists of several files.

The `index.js` of the package just imports and re exports the public classes and APIs/

When I install the package from NPM I get the following error when I try to use the custom package:

```
Error: Cannot find module './openapi'
Require stack:
- .../node_modules/.../dist/index.js
```

I checked dist folder in the module dir in node_modules and the files are there.

I assume there is an issue with the relative path inside the node_modules

One option to fix this is to bundle everything into a single file, but I would prefer to keep multiple files.
What options are there to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` files are ignored. There were after all some ignored local files that needed a to be pushed.